# select element list under textbox

Tags: java, selenium

In a web page there is a field which name is *Street name*:* and when I put in it  only a number , a list of addresses ,which have that number, appears under that field.
When I click on one of those addresses ,this field contains this address, and other fields as the city or the postal code are automatically populated with the values present in the Street name.
Now I want to do the same with `Java` using Junit with the libraries of Selenium. So I want that Junit clicks on one of the elements of the list which appears under the field *Street name*:* after having inserted a number in this field.

```
private WebDriver driver= new FireFoxDriver();
WebElement street_name=driver.findElement(By.id("street_name"));

String pac_input="3";

street_name.sendKeys(pac_input);
```

I insert into the `webelement`, `street_name` the value "3" and
under this box appears a list of addresses which have the number "3"
I want that JUNIT clicks on one of the elements of this list
Which java command should I use for filling this webelement
with the value selected in the list which appears under this
box `street_name` ?

How can I do it?
Thanks for the help,
Alberto

Comment: what's the type[tag name] of the element.Is it `select` or `li`

Comment: maybe show some HTML code of the site when the popup is shown`?